# CSS method to include IE6 hacks

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6

- CSS has @import, right?
- IE6 understands `*html selector` hack, right?

Is it possible to combine them like

```
//*html @import url(ie6hacks.css);
```

or, possibly,

```
//*html { @import url(ie6hacks.css); }
```

?

Good browsers must skip this, will it still work in IE6? How does it look as a solution? I can clearly see it looks ugly as normal CSS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to combine them like

```
* html @import url(ie6hacks.css);
```

No. at-rules like @import are not selectors, so cannot be combined with other selectors.

There are ways to make at-rules work as hacks, for example this:

```
@import url(/* no! */iehacks.css);
```

will be loaded by IE6/7 but not the other browsers. However, I wouldn't recommend using it; this sort of thing can be really fragile. This particular example is also invalid CSS.

As Daniel says, if you want separate .css files for hacks, the best approach is a conditionally-included link tag. The beauty of “* html” is that you can put hack-rules in the same stylesheet, which is easier to manage if there are only a few of them; if you're having a separate style sheet anyway, it offers no advantage.

IMO “* html” for IE6 is the only hack it's still legitimate to use today. All the box model stuff is dead along with IE5 — assuming you're not using IE6 Quirks Mode, which you shouldn't — and the other browsers, even IE7, are generally too good to be able to attack with a simple hack; the few hacks that can target them are too complex/fragile/invalid to really use.

(And as the inventor of the Simplified Box Model Hack, I say a hearty good riddance to them.)

Comment: Hahaha, that's a neat trick, though every time I learn a new IE hack I feel my brain expand with knowledge and contract in pain at the same time.

Answer (score 12):

Why bother with that wacky hack when you could use conditional comments to include just the CSS you need?

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie-6.0.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Some resources:

- http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html
- http://virtuelvis.com/archives/2004/02/css-ie-only

If you really must use @import, you can take advantage of the fact that IE doesn't follow specs for the @import rule.  Normally it must be the very first think in a stylesheet or style tag, or it's completely ignored.  However, IE6 (at least when I tested it) doesn't seem to care.  Along those lines, you can do this:

```
<style type="text/css">
.NotARealClass { }

@import url("ie-style.css");
</style>
```

Note that I haven't tested this in anything besides FF3 (where it fails to load ie-style.css) and IE6 (where it loads it anyways).  Your mileage may vary.

Comment: I know that, thanks. Why? Because i thought it would be clever and nice to keep CSS hacks inside CSS.

Comment: This is the way to go if all your ie6-specific css is in a separate file. If you have very little ie6-specific css, you could use the underscore-hack, eg. _width gets interpreted as width by ie6 (but not ie7), that will not validate though..

Comment: Conditional comments aren't a hack so much as taking advantage of one browser's extended feature set.  Selector hacks most certainly are.

Comment: @temoto: yes it's nice to keep css hacks together in one file. Some projects I've worked in didn't have a common header, but they all included a base css file. Having to backfix all of the pages to include the conditional comments would stink, so a trick like you're asking would have been great.

Comment: Thanks for add-up Daniel, that .NotRealClass looks very interesting technique.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately the `*html` hack cannot be used to import other stylesheets.

[Here is an article](http://www.communitymx.com/content/article.cfm?page=2&cid=C37E0) explaining that hack and others that are useful for attacking IE-specific bugs.

Comment: Thank you for clear answer. Unfortunately i'm out of votes today :)