# CSS Feature-Query for "safe" overflow keyword

Tags: css, flexbox, feature-detection

I'd like to conditionally apply `justify-content: safe center` based on browser support like

```css
@supports (justify-content: safe center) {
  div {
    justify-content: safe center;
  }
}
```

Both Blink and Webkit which currently do not support this keyword pass the condition while not actually supporting the `safe` keyword as seen by the overflowed second line in below example:

https://jsfiddle.net/pgw3t1hq/

Is there a way to get these browsers to fail the condition and reflect what they actually support?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639999/is-there-a-way-to-do-browser-specific-conditional-css-inside-a-css-file

Comment: potential alternative: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33454533/3597276

Comment: Yes, seems like browser detection is the way to go until the browsers fix their bugs or implement it. Issue is that they do recognize `safe center` as valid syntax while not actually supporting the feature itself, so `@supports` is a lie in this case.